# PHP - For loop only writing one submission to MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a database where I would like the order_ID's to be put into two tables. This works but the issue I have is that the loop is only iterating once. If anyone could help and explain where I have gone wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['shop_id'];
$shopid = $_SESSION['shop_id'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'aurora');
if (!isset($con)) {
    echo "Connection to Aurora System failed.";
}

if (isset($_POST['items'])) {
    echo "True";
} else {
    echo "false";
}

$valid = true;
$date =  date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO orders_new (user_submitted, order_date, customer_ID) VALUES ('$username', '$date', '$shopid')";
if ($valid == true) {
    $ordersubmit2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
    echo "Success!";
} 

$count = $_POST['items'];
for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    $idinsert = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    $product = $_POST['product'.$i];
    $nicotine = $_POST['nicotine'.$i];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'.$i];
    echo $product;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO orders_detail (orders_id ,product, variant, quantity) VALUES ('$idinsert', '".$product."', '".$nicotine."', '".$qty."')";
    $ordersubmit = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
```

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all.

Comment: what is the value of `$count`? just `echo` it before the loop.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/41675307/1415724 - Plus, we don't know what the HTML form / inputs look like, so you should probably include it in your question and probable JS etc. My guess; the element(s) is/are probably not treated as an array.

Comment: another tip: if you connect to `root` , with or without password, maybe you shouldn't show it to everybody (you could replace them by `****` in the shown code)

Comment: Yeah it is in to regards of my previous question, The SQL injection protection will come later, im well aware but for the moment locally it's just more speed rather than precision.

Comment: _Suggestion:_ It's better to build it secure from the start. Otherwise, you will still need to refactor a bunch of your code and will probably introduce new bugs. Another thing regarding not escaping data, if any of the values you're inserting contains a `'`-character, or if it ends in a backslash, your query will fail.

Comment: None of the escaping data contains either characters, this is what is confusing me haha

Comment: So far I've echoed out the results and the loop is doing a full loop which is fine, yet it seems to be just the MySql that is only writing once but, to be honest I can't seem to find an issue with the code?

Answer (score 1):

Was my own fault, the order_id was a primary key hence the loop stopping due to only allowing unique values.